# Ensure change of a string doesn't go unnoticed in other spots of a large program

Tags: python, python-3.4

`ALL_POSSIBLE_DOG_TOYS` is a *large* list containing the names of every single toy a dog owner can buy for his dog.

```
ALL_POSSIBLE_DOG_TOYS = ['large_chew_bone', 'treat_ball', .... ]
```

If the owner has bought a specific toy, it can affect the dog's happiness in various ways depending on some factors (e.g. dog breed, age etc).

Therefore, in some places of my code I need to check whether a specific toy is purchased by the owner, that is, a toy is part of his `self.toys_purchased` list.

e.g.

```
# Check if a specific toy is bought.

if 'treat_ball' in self.toys_purchased:
    # Do stuff with treat balls.
    # ...
```

I need to perform the above checks in various locations of a 15k LOC program.
I also want to ensure that if I ever change the name of a toy in `ALL_POSSIBLE_DOG_TOYS`, **I will not forget to also change** its name in my `if` checks.

---

One way to achieve that is by doing the following:

```
DOG_TOYS_AS_DICT = {
    'large_chew_bone': 'large_chew_bone',  
    'treat_ball': 'treat_ball',
    ...
    ...
}
```

That is, create a dict with each key being the same as its value.

Then use `DOG_TOYS_AS_DICT` values instead of using directly the actual toy name:

```
# Check if a specific toy is bought.

if DOG_TOYS_AS_DICT['treat_ball'] in self.toys_purchased:
    # Do stuff with treat balls.
    # ...
```

This way if I ever change `'treat_ball'` in `ALL_POSSIBLE_DOG_TOYS` to `'ball_with_treats'` I would get a (desired) KeyError in locations where I `# Check if a specific toy is bought`, and so that I can change `'treat_ball'` to the new string.

---

**Question:**
Is there a clearer way to ensure that changes to any of the toy names doesn't go unnoticed in the rest of the program?

Comment: simply use named variables? `LARGE_CHEW_BONE = 'some_str'`. After that simply use name instead of string.

Comment: @ŁukaszR. That is not very practical since I would have to create dozens of such names. (i will edit accordingly to clarify that `ALL_POSSIBLE_DOG_TOYS` is big).

Comment: @Fermi paradox: Use `locals()['my_var'] = 'my_var'`? Like `for toy in ALL_POSSIBLE_DOG_TOYS: locals()[toy] = toy`. Now you will have a variable named `large_chew_bone` containing `'large_chew_bone'`

Comment: @mshsayem Sounds like a nice idea, but since it's a huge program i don't know if i have a method or function having the same name as a toy (which would cause bugs). So in my case it would still be risky.

Comment: Note that, unless you particularly *need* order, `ALL_POSSIBLE_DOG_TOYS ` should be a `set`, not a `list`. Could you give some more context for this - why are you checking for specific toys? If it's just for testing, why not add a dummy toy to the list for that purpose *within the test setup*, then remove it after the tests finish?

Comment: @jonrsharpe If the owner has bought a specific toy, it can affect the dog's happiness in a way depending on various factors (e.g. dog breed, age etc). Therefor i need to check if that toy is bought, in order to apply its effects to dog's happiness.

Comment: @Fermiparadox then shouldn't this behaviour be encapsulated in a class, rather than using a string and checking which it is? At the very least, making a dictionary `{specific_toy: happiness_impact, ...}` would get you a `KeyError` if you change one but not the other. Please *edit the question* to fully explain the situation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Edited question. "encapsulated in a class" - You mean creating a class/method specifically designed to check whether a toy is in `self.purchased_toys`?

Comment: No, I mean making `ALL_POSSIBLE_DOG_TOYS` and `self.purchased_toys` lists of instances of a new class, `DogToy`, rather than of strings. That way you can store a toy's impact on a dog's happiness right there in the list alongside its name and any other attributes. If you implement `__eq__` and `__hash__` on that class, you can still make them sets rather than lists (for `O(1)` membership tests), too.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways - edit your code in IDE, such like PyCharm, so when you need to rename - use refactoring menu, which will change name everywhere in your program.

Comment: I can't do it. The 'rename' option in 'Refactor' is grayed out, when i try to rename a string.

Comment: PyCharm will (optionally) search in strings when you change an identifier, but I don't think this would work for changing a literal string.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create an external database, containing the names of those toys, categories, nicknames, article numbers, ...? There seems to be a `DB_API` library that you can use for accessing MySQL, Oracle, ... databases. Or am I missing something in your question?